# Get related tags in mysql (need help)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have a table in mysql

Table name: related_tags

```
 tag_1   |   tag_2
....................
 iphone      ipod
 ipad        ipone
 iphone      mac
 iphone      apple
 ipod        ipone
 iphone      ipod
 apple       iphone
```

i want to print related tags to the iphone from this table..

and the tags which is used more times with iphone should be at 1st

e-g: ipod (used 3 times), apple used 2 times

ipod should be 1st and apple must be 2nd and so on.

what will be the exect query

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: you need show with a sql or script php??

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you're numbering your columns shows that something is wrong with your schema in the first place. You should have one table containing all tags (tagID, tagName) and then a second table where you store the relations (tagID, tagID). This way you can easily query your relations.

Comment: i already have a tags table that contain tag id's and tag names.. but when ever same tag added any where in my site a new row added so tag with same name may have many id's. @markus

Comment: that should NOT happen. when someone re-uses a tag, it should not be added again, instead an entry into a third table should be made (userID, tagID).